# Sorting DAM asset and Cq page based on last modified

Tags: search, aem, query-builder, dam

I am trying to perform a freetext search on all the Cq:Page and dam:Asset with the ordering being the last modified.
I have created the Query for search which is as below:

```
1_group.p.or=true
1_group.1_type=cq:Page
1_group.2_type=dam:Asset
2_group.p.or=true
2_group.1_path=/content
2_group.2_path=/content/dam
fulltext=text
p.limit=-1
```

Now I need to sort the results based on last modified. But since cq:Page has property jcr:content/cq:lastModified and dam:Asset has property jcr:content/jcr:lastModified, I am unable to figure out which property should i use in the orderby field of predicate. Is there any way to form a predicate which uses different property values for pages and assets during sorting. Please let me know if we can achieve this in a single query.

Regards,
Shailesh

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating a custom [AbstractPredicateEvaluator](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/AbstractPredicateEvaluator.html) and overriding the [getOrderByComparator](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/AbstractPredicateEvaluator.html#getOrderByComparator(com.day.cq.search.Predicate,%20com.day.cq.search.eval.EvaluationContext)) with your own comparator.  Then you would register your custom predicate evaluator for your [Query](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/Query.html) by calling [registerPredicateEvaluator](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/Query.html#registerPredicateEvaluator(java.lang.String,%20com.day.cq.search.eval.PredicateEvaluator)).

In the example below, you can use whatever you'd like for the `customSort.sortby` property.  This can be useful if your comparator handles multiple types of sorting.  You can get this information from the predicate via `predicate.get("sortby")`.

```
QueryBuilder builder = resourceResolver.adaptTo(QueryBuilder.class);
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("1_group", "true");
params.put("1_group.1_type", "cq:Page");
params.put("1_group.2_type", "dam:Asset");
params.put("2_group.p.or", "true");
params.put("2_group.1_path", "/content");
params.put("2_group.2_path", "/content/dam");
params.put("fulltext", text);
params.put("p.limit", "-1");
params.put("customSort.sortby", "last-modified");
PredicateGroup pg = PredicateGroup.create(params);
Query query = builder.createQuery(pg, resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
query.registerPredicateEvaluator("customSort", new CustomSortPredicateEvaluator());
SearchResult result = query.getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no way since they are differenet type (cq:lastModified & jcr:lastModified), Even you use SQL2 like this (SELECT p.* FROM [nt:base] AS p WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(p, '/content') AND ( p.[jcr:primaryType]='dam:Asset' OR p.[jcr:primaryType]='cq:Page')) there no way to use ORDER BY.

Have to use Java code for sorting. 
Keep your Query, get QueryResult to List and do Comparator Sort